# Use Multiple Django {% extends inOne.html %}

Tags: html, django

Is this possible? I don't want **A** *extends* **B** *extends* **C** scenario in this case.

[image]

Comment: Use include instead of extends. Those are slower, but are what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [{% include '' %} tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#include):

> Loads a template and renders it with the current context. This is a way of “including” other templates within a template.